# TIMESTAMP para data/hora em PT-BR no MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Como faço para retornar a data brasileira em coluna do banco de dados para que ela ficar assim `29-04-2020 17:02:02`, porque ele tá retornando assim `2020-04-29 17:02:02`.

```
create database teste;
use teste;

CREATE TABLE cliente (
  cd_cliente INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR(30),
  cpf VARCHAR(14),
  telefone VARCHAR(15),
  email VARCHAR(50),
  cidade VARCHAR(30),
  bairro VARCHAR(30),
  rua VARCHAR(30),
  numero INT,
  data_cadastro TIMESTAMP(0)
);

insert into cliente (nome,cpf,telefone,email,cidade,bairro,rua,numero,data_cadastro)
values
('João','111.111.111-01','(77) 12345-1234','joao@gmail.com','Guanambi','Santo Carlos','Alguma',123,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
select * from cliente;
```

Comment: Utilize a função `DATE_FORMAT` para obter a data no formato desejado para exibição.

Comment: @anonimo onde coloco ```DATE_FORMAT```? Tem como descrever em código?

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro você incluir no modo default a data e somente na hora da query transformar para o formato desejado.
Tipo:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2020-04-29', '%d de %M de %Y');
```

Você pode setar o banco para pt-br também, o que não recomendo porque pode afetar outros usuários/aplicações.

```sql
SET GLOBAL lc_time_names=pt_BR;
```